# FullCalendar add on by drag and drop on event

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I am stuck here to add on item on event by drag and drop, while i'm drag and drop item on event callback function not working and while drop on without on event callback function working
**call back function code below**:

```
 dropAccept: ".StaffList",
        drop: function (date) {
            debugger
            var a = date.draggedEl.dataset.userid;

        }
```

**Draggable code below**

```
calendar.render();
    new Draggable(containerEl, {
        itemSelector: '.StaffList',
        helper: 'clone',
        create: false,                 
        opacity: 0.75

    });
```

Comment: i think you need this [here](https://fullcalendar.io/#demos)

Comment: Sorry but your description doesn't make sense, it's all one big jumble of words without any grammatical meaning. Please try and edit your question to clarify what you mean.